# Reading Text from file into nested loop

Tags: c, loops, nested

I am having some trouble reading some input from a file into a multidimensional array. I have two nested for loops which print out different outputs, but I want them to print out the same output. I have been stuck on it for hours, and may just be in a mental block. The input file is a 9x9 set of numbers. My problem occurs at [0][8],[1,8], etc.. as it just copies the value from [1,0],[2,0], etc... Heres the first nested loop and its output:

```
for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    if(j!=0){
        printf("%c",fgetc(file));
    }
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        array[j][k]=fgetc(file);
        printf("array[%i][%i] :%c \n",j,k,array[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Some Output:

```
array[0][0] :8   
array[0][1] :5   
array[0][2] :2     
array[0][3] :7    
array[0][4] :1    
array[0][5] :3    
array[0][6] :9   
array[0][7] :4  
array[0][8] :6  

array[1][0] :4  
array[1][1] :3  
array[1][2] :1  
array[1][3] :9  
array[1][4] :2  
array[1][5] :6  
array[1][6] :5  
array[1][7] :7  
array[1][8] :8  

array[2][0] :9  
array[2][1] :7  
array[2][2] :6  
array[2][3] :5  
array[2][4] :4  
array[2][5] :8  
array[2][6] :2  
array[2][7] :3  
array[2][8] :1
```

Here's my second nested loop which is located directly under this previous set of code. All I wanted to do was read the contents of the multi-dimensional array I just wrote to.

```
for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){   
        printf("array[%i][%i] :%c \n",j,k,array[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And here's this loop's output:

```
array[0][0] :8  
array[0][1] :5  
array[0][2] :2  
array[0][3] :7  
array[0][4] :1  
array[0][5] :3  
array[0][6] :9  
array[0][7] :4  
array[0][8] :4  

array[1][0] :4  
array[1][1] :3  
array[1][2] :1  
array[1][3] :9  
array[1][4] :2  
array[1][5] :6  
array[1][6] :5  
array[1][7] :7  
array[1][8] :9  

array[2][0] :9  
array[2][1] :7  
array[2][2] :6  
array[2][3] :5  
array[2][4] :4  
array[2][5] :8  
array[2][6] :2  
array[2][7] :3  
array[2][8] :7
```

Comment: What does the declaration of array look like?  If it is allocated, what does the allocation look like?  Your problem is most likely there.

Comment: The answer is unlikely to be in the code you've shown.  You mention multi-threading in the tags; these loops are running concurrently in different threads?  What is the coordination between the threads?  How does the second (print-only) thread/loop know not to go further than the first (read and print) thread/loop has got to?  Your indentation could be clearer, too.  (Don't use tabs; use 4 spaces per level on SO).

Comment: I declared my array globally as int array[8][8] and it does have threads in the program but this occurs when I compile the program without threads. Also this is just in int main().

Comment: So, the multithreading tag is immaterial since this code is single-threaded.  Further, the first loop is run first to read data, and then the second loop is run to validate the data.  Is that what you're telling us?

Comment: If your array is 8x8, then your valid loop indices are 0..7, not 0..8.  You're overwriting the bounds of your array, leading to wholly undefined behaviour.  It would help to show us the relevant fragment of the data file.  Why do read and print (but otherwise jettison) one character in the loop?  What's reading the newlines?

Comment: exactly, this problem doesn't have to do with the multithreading in my code so I should have disregarded that. And yes, the first nested loop is to read the data into the array from a file which contains 9 lines of 9 numbers with no spaces. And yes the second loop is to validate it. Thus something went wrong between my first printf statement and my second printf statement.

Comment: I botched the terminology its a 9x9 matrix. So it should be [0..8][0..8]

Comment: If your declaration says `int array[8][8];`, it is an 8x8 matrix with subscripts in range 0..7 in each dimension.  You should be able to make an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help; you're almost there.  You could map `FILE *fp = stdin;` so it reads from standard input; you can show us the data file.

Comment: you can tell you've declared it [8][8] because the last number you are having problems with is the first number of the next entry

Comment: O wow, I completely forgot about the basics :/, this is embarrassing. However why does my first loop output correctly even when I messed up the declaration. This fixed it however, I believe.

Comment: It's C; C assumes you know what you are doing.  There is no array subscript checking.  Get used to it.  The first loops works because it reports what it reads as it reads.  You don't go back and re-print the prior row of data; if you did, you'd find it was already over-written.

Comment: And now my sudoku validation code works successfully!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the array is declared as:

```
int array[8][8];
```

but the array is supposed to be 9x9 (hence `int array[9][9];`).  If your array is 8x8, then your valid loop indices are 0..7, not 0..8. You're overwriting the bounds of your array, leading to wholly undefined behaviour.  Notably, once you're on the ninth line, you are writing completely outside of the bounds of the array, scribbling on who knows what other data.

The overwriting shown is precisely what you would expect in the circumstances.  The first digit of the second row overwrites the last digit of the 'first row', so instead of seeing 6 as it was entered, the code sees 4.

First loop:

```
array[0][8] :6  

array[1][0] :4
```

Second loop:

```
array[0][8] :4  

array[1][0] :4
```